# RadGrid master/Details Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

Ive got my main table lets say with users and second with orders details. Now lets say that PK in users table is ID. In orders I have only card number column by which I can decide which rows should be displayed. In each row of users CardNumber Is as well.

I know how to create dataSource for Orders table which uses control parameter:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvUsers" DefaultValue="0" Name="ID"
                                      PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
```

Thanks to that I can get userId which is PK of the Users table and use it in the select query for orders. But I need to use not userId but CardID.

What should I do to make it the easiest way to rebind orders table everytime selected row i users table is changed based on the cardNumber value of newly selected row from users table.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

ok Ive figured it out.

It is enough to add key to `<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="id, userId`

And then You can use it in sql data source:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvUsers" DefaultValue="0" Name="userId"
                                  PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
```

Comment: A co-worker just asked me how to do this, and 7 years later, even the Telerik documentation isn't clear on this (or, at least I couldn't find it). Thought you'd be happy to know this was useful to someone in 2019. :)